# Is my rewrite code correct?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write rewrite code for my customer's site.  I have no way of verifying if it's correct because I don't have access to the server yet. I know that sounds strange but it's what I have to accept and work around.

I plan to put this in the root htaccess file on the server. Bottom line is this URL does not work:

http://www.regions.noaa.gov/gulf-mexico/index.php/highlights/restore-act-passed/

So when the above fires, I want it to permanently redirect to:

http://www.regions.noaa.gov/gulf-mexico/highlights/restore-act-passed/

Here is what I have

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^regions\.noaa\.gov$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.regions\.noaa\.gov$
RewriteRule ^gulf\-mexico\/index\.php\/highlights\/restore\-act\-passed\/$ "http\:\/\/www\.regions\.noaa\.gov\/gulf\-mexico\/highlights\/restore\-act\-passed\/" [R=301,L]
```

I'd appreciate any feedback on this.  Thanks.

---

UPDATE - thanks to all who replied.  Here's what I don't understand.  I found this code on my web hosting company's code generator.  It seems to work:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^designerandpublisher.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.designerandpublisher.com$
RewriteRule ^services.html$ "http\://www.regions.noaa.gov/gulf-mexico/highlights/restore-act-passed/" [R=301,L]

Comment: You _do_ know that you can install Apache on computers that are not your customer's server, right?

Comment: Y\o\u a\r\e e\s\c\a\p\i\n\g w\a\y t\o\o m\u\c\h t\h\e\r\e …

Comment: Uhh, not sure I unserstand what you mean by "escaping way too much?"

Comment: Yes, I do know and I have an XAMPP - but I've been unable to get it working locally.  Will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do like this and works fine.

IF user enter in the URL with highlights/restore-act-passed/ THEN will display contents from index.php/highlights/restore-act-passed/ in the browser.

```
# [NC]   Means “No Case”, so it doesn’t matter whether the domain name was written in upper case, lower case or a mixture of the two.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^highlights/restore-act-passed/?$ index.php/highlights/restore-act-passed/  [NC]
```

IF the user enter in the URL with index.php/highlights/restore-act-passed/ THEN will display contents from _http://%{HTTP_HOST}/gulf-mexico/highlights/restore-act-passed/

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/highlights/restore-act-passed/?$ _http://%{HTTP_HOST}/gulf-mexico/highlights/restore-act-passed/  [NC]
```

Comment: since stackoverflow do not accept add links with http, I replace it with _http in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the HTTP_HOST, unless you will have multiple domains coming through here (add-ons, subdomains, parked domains, etc.). If you *do* want to specify it, it can be simplified to one line:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?regions\.noaa\.gov$
RewriteRule ^gulf\-mexico\/index\.php\/highlights\/restore\-act\-passed\/$ "http\:\/\/www\.regions\.noaa\.gov\/gulf\-mexico\/highlights\/restore\-act\-passed\/" [R=301,L]
```

Actually, a subdomain doesn't even *need* the www, but it doesn't hurt. Then, in the rewrite rule, you only need to escape specific metacharacters in the pattern, and none in the replacement string:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?regions\.noaa\.gov$
RewriteRule ^gulf-mexico/index\.php/highlights/restore-act-passed(/)?$ http://www.regions.noaa.gov/gulf-mexico/highlights/restore-act-passed/ [R=301,L]
```

I also made the last (trailing) / optional. Since you're going to the same domain, there is no need to repeat it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?regions\.noaa\.gov$
RewriteRule ^gulf-mexico/index\.php/highlights/restore-act-passed(/)?$ /gulf-mexico/highlights/restore-act-passed/ [R=301,L]
```

The 301 code says to alert search engines that this URL or URI has permanently moved (it will show up changed in a browser address bar, too, so human visitors can choose to rebookmark it).

As this appears to be an SEO URI, presumably it will be translated into a dynamic format (`/gulf-mexico/index.php?area=highlights&item=restore-act-passed`). That means that the above rewrite has to be done *before* any SEO-to-dynamic translation. An alternative would be to directly translate it to dynamic format right here, but since you're giving a 301, presumably you want the SEO format to show in a browser or search engine result.